# When will the Museum of Roman Civilization in Rome re-open?

Tags: italy, event-based-effects, rome

According to [Google maps](https://www.google.it/maps/place/Museum+of+Roman+Civilization/),  the Museum of Roman Civilization is "permanently closed". But [their website](http://www.museociviltaromana.it/servizi/avvisi/chiusura_del_museo_della_civilta_romana2) kinda implies that the closure is temporary and that it'll re-open.

Is it currently known when the museum might re-open?

Comment: Did you try emailing to ask them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.museociviltaromana.it/servizi/news/al_via_i_lavori_al_museo_della_civilta_romana_aperto_il_cantiere_da_venerdi_9_giugno_2017) article:

> Si prevede che termineranno entro la fine del mese di ottobre 2018.

**EN:**

> (The work) is expected to end by the end of October 2018.

But again it's Rome, and things might get delayed! :)

Comment: ...works to be followed, within six months, by technical tests and authorisations from the Fire Department, according to the same article...